# HIGHs documentation for Python Scipy module

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, scipy-optimize, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a REST Api that uses `SciPy's linprog`.
While using this function I have get many correct results but sometimes I get errors. But I am unable to find proper documentation for different possible errors.

The error statements are like,
`HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is At lower/fixed bound`
or
`HiGHS Status 8: model_status is Infeasible; primal_status is Basic`.
I am unable to find what the primal status is and does it means to be basic and lower/fixed bound. Is there any Documentation for these errrors or any online repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This documentation for HiGHS, which is the software that scipy is using under the hood, might be helpful to you: https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/dev/terminology/#Optimization-outcomes

That specific error message is telling you that the constraints which you have specified cannot be satisfied. There might be a flaw in the logic you use to define the bounds of the search space.